# In the WSO2 DAS dashboard, the gadget (graphs) data disappear when I maximize or refresh

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I'm using WSO2 Data Analytics Server. I receive my events with an HTTP receiver and I did a dashboard to see informations in real time. When a event is received, the graphs are updated well but if I try to maximize the gadgets (or even refresh the page) the graph data disappear. Anybody know why ?

[Picutre 1: Before I maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAW9U.png)

[Picture 2: When I'm maximizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szUAH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2DAS real time charts, the visualization will be done for data received after rendering the page. When you maximize the gadget it will be rendered again, so therefore it will show data received after maximizing. If you want to show stored data, its better to use a batch provider for charts.

Comment: Thank you so much !